# How to determine if Gemfile or gemspec has all required gem dependencies

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require, gemfile

Say you have a Ruby project A and you install the gem `make_everything_work` so that project A will work on the system you are developing on. It would have a line in the gemfile like this

```
# Project A: Gemfile
gem 'make_everything_work', '~> 1.0'
...
```

as well as a line elsewhere in the code like this

```
# Project A: other file
require 'make_everything_work'
...
```

Then you start another project B that also makes use of the gem `make_everything_work`, however, you never list it in your Gemfile or gemspec file.

```
# Project B: other file
require 'make_everything_work'
...
```

The project still works on your machine, because you already installed the gem for project A, even though you never included it in your Gemfile dependencies.

Is there a way to check that any gems required by your project are listed as a dependency in your Gemfile/gemspec file?

Answer (score 0):

You can test this by setting up `rvm` or `rbenv`

Meaning a clean separate environments for Project A and Project B.